# How to upload a file with all entire path?

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs, file

I would like to drag a file from my computer to my app, 
and then save its name and its full path.

But I can only retrieve its name and not the full path.
How can I do this?

This is the beginning of what I did:

```
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
        var data = event.dataTransfer.items;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
            var f = data[i].getAsFile();
            var name = f.name;
        }
}
```

Thank U.

Comment: I think you cannot get the full path of the uploaded file due to security reasons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46710226/1723335 ... doesn't seem possible with drag drop to me, I find the same posted from others.

Comment: so what can I do